# DataGridView import .xml file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I can't figure this out and I have been trying for hours.
I am trying to load an .xml file into my DataGridView. I already managed to save the DataGridColumn to an .xml file like this:

```
SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
savefile.FileName = "Test.xml";
savefile.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml";
    if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        DataTable dT = GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView1);
        DataSet dS = new DataSet();
        dS.Tables.Add(dT);
        dS.WriteXml(File.OpenWrite(savefile.FileName));
    }
```

By running those lines of code, the .xml file shows something like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>123235435</Column1>
    <Column2>dffg</Column2>
    <Column3>ghh</Column3>
    <Column4>N/A</Column4>
    <Column5>100k</Column5>
    <Column6>False</Column6>
    <Column7>False</Column7>
  </Table1>
  <Table1 />
</NewDataSet>
```

This works well (I think), however when I try to load it through various methods, it either doesn't load it at all or I suddenly can't add rows programmatically anymore. I want the file to be loaded on Forms1_Load event and I want to be able to save it again to the same file.

Please let me know if I am unclear and need to elaborate more. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: GetDataTableFromDGV Method:

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dataGridView1)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                if (column.Visible)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add();
                }
            }

            object[] cellValues = new object[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
            }

            return dt;


        }
```

Comment: Since you used a DataSet to store the data: `var ds = new DataSet(); ds.ReadXml([Your XML File Path]); [DataGridView].DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`. Is this what you tried?

Comment: @Jimi Sorry for the late response, but yes I tried something like that, and it only added the corresponding amount of rows, but without any data in the columns. What I mean by this is that all the columns are empty, but it did generate 2 rows. Obviously I would like to have the columns filled in as well. I have no idea what could cause this problem. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: So, the data is loaded (you have two new Rows). Have you checked some basic stuff, as whether the DGV DefaultCellStyle ForeColor is the same as the BackColor (so you cannot *see* the text. It would show if you click a cell)? -- Can you show what `GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView1)` is doing? (when you have relevant methods in your code, you should post the body of these methods).

Comment: Of course, stupid of me not to show that haha. I've added it into my post. Also, the text should be visible as the colors are different from each other.

Comment: It's just for reference, since you said that, inspecting the file's content, the data is stored, as shown here. 1. I suggest to write the data like this: `[DataSet].WriteXml(savefile.FileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);`: `File.OpenWrite()` keeps the Stream opened and you're not closing it. 2. You should use a DataTable as the DataSource of your DGV. If you want to remove Columns (to avoid the hidden ones? Why?), the DataTable has `Remove()` and `RemoveAt()` methods. Don't use `object[]` like that, you'll have all strings in the end. As of now, you're also saving the `NewRow` object.

Comment: I'd understand the missing schema if you needed to store the data for other reasons, but since you're loading it back in a DataTable to use as DataSource, you should save the schema, so the Columns will have their original DataType when reading back the XML. Otherwise, the DataType is lost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have changed the way it saves the file to your example so it now saves the schema. However, I don't really understand with what you mean in the second part of your answer. I must be doing something wrong because it still loads empty rows. I'm sorry if I have miss seen something obvious.

Comment: Have you removed `File.OpenWrite()`? Are you sure that you're providing the correct path when you're reading that file back (post the related code)? Are you using a DataTable as the DataSource of your DGV, for input? If so, change `DataTable dT = GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView1);` in `DataTable dT = dataGridView1.DataSource as DadaTable`. Do you have Columns set in the Designer? A DataSource set later may add Columns to the existing. If so, remove them completely and setup a DataTable (setting its Columns' DataType correctly) to use as DataSource for your DGV. Try again the whole process.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you! You have cleared up so many things. I have now managed to clear the columns before loading in the new ones, because it indeed added the columns to the old ones instead of replacing them. However, I still have a problem (I know, sorry). When I save the current grid, it doesn't save the column names with it. Apart from that, I also can't seem to add spaces or ":" to the names even though I can do that in the designer. Sorry for the many, many questions I am asking you, I'm very new with gridDataViews. Thanks again!

Comment: Of course the Columns' Names are saved! In the XML Schema, the `xs:element` corresponding to the Columns' definition saves both the `name` attribute (the actual Column name) and the `Caption` attribute (the string used to *present* the Column, it will be the Header text in a DGV Column), corresponding to the `[DataColumn].Caption` property. Never use spaces to define the `name` of a Column (anywhere), you can use spaces or other *special* chars to define the `Caption`.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you once again for your answer! Unfortunately it does not save the column header text. It does however save the name, but the wrong name. I have changed the names of the columns (Not just the header, also the name) to something other than Column1 or Column2 etc. however it still shows Column1 etc. in the XML file: https://hastebin.com/imusobekez.xml. I would want to have the column captions to be the same as the ones in the designer. I have actually encountered the same problem as before as well. I can't seem to add any rows programmatically with this solution.

Comment: Also, it saves all of the columns as Strings even though 2 of them are comboboxes. Again, sorry for all of the questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Column's Name and Caption are defined in the DataTable schema: e.g., `var dt = new DataTable("TestTable"); DataColumn[] dcs = { new DataColumn() { AllowDBNull = false, AutoIncrement = true, AutoIncrementStep = 1, Caption = "Idx", ColumnName = "IDX", DataType = typeof(int) }, new DataColumn() { Caption = "Bool", ColumnName = "BoolValue", DataType = typeof(bool) }}; dt.Columns.AddRange(dcs);`, to define an auto-incrementing Primary Key Column and a `bool` Column. -- ComboBoxes have a completely different DataSource, you need to save it on a different XML file.

Comment: If you want to work with just strings, you serialize to XML or JSON directly, without using a DataSet and set the `DataPropertyName` of the DGV Colunms you have in the Designer. Or use a database.

Comment: @WoJo, please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to work with some minor changes and I am not sure what the invisible columns are doing. If the code originally, reads in the data from an XML file and you set the grids data source to the data read from the XML file, then you make some of the columns invisible, then later the code “writes” the grid data “back” into the same XML file while “ignoring” the invisible columns, then when you write the file, you will lose the invisible columns you started with. It is unclear how the invisible columns come into play here and if you may actually need them when you “write” the XML file.

Also, when the code creates a `DataTable` from a `DataGridView` in the `GetDataTableFromDGV` method… I am not sure why you do not use the column names from the grid when creating the `DataTable` columns. Example, in the code there is a line…

```
dt.Columns.Add();
```

This is adding a “blank” new column. The first one would have a default name of “Column1.” Is there some reason you are not using the grid column names here? Something like…

```
dt.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText);
```

This will match the `DataTable` column name to the same name the grid has. It is unclear if this is intended.

Lastly, in reference to something you stated in the comments….

> *”I can't seem to add any rows programmatically with this solution.”*

This will depend on “how” you are trying to add the rows programmatically. When a grid has a `DataSource` (which in this case it obviously does), the user can “add/delete/edit” cells/rows directly in the grid if the grid allows this. The changes the user makes in the grid are automatically changed in the `DataSource`. This is by design.

However, if the code tries to programmatically “add/remove” rows DIRECTLY INTO THE GRID, you will get an error stating that you can NOT programmatically add rows to a data bound grid. If you want to add a row to the grid “programmatically”, then you have to add the row to the `DataSource`. In this case the `DataTable`. In the code, instead of adding rows to the grid itself, you add the new row to the `DataTable` and it will automatically display in the grid.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: `ds.WriteXml(savefile.FileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);` then `ds.ReadXml([File Path], XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);`. Streams are not required here, you're just reading from/writing to a local file, not over a network. The default encoding can be left as it is, most probably.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the info. I am obviously not proficient at XML. When I used the stand-alone line… `ds.WriteXml(savefile.FileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)` … it appeared to leave the file open. I would try and read the file after writing and kept getting an error that the file was already being used. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That overload (with File path and options), uses a `XmlTextWriter` (and reader) that is closed right after the operation is complete (even if exceptions are raised for some reason).

Comment: @Jimi Wellll… crap. It works fine now. Initially, I was under the impression it would work as you said, however the error kept popping up. I should have researched the documentation before I jumped down that rabbit hole. I must be getting tired and cranky. Thanks for the info, I will remove that part in my answer.

Comment: @Jimi Ahhh… I think I see where I was getting the error. I was using the posted code… `dS.WriteXml(File.OpenWrite(savefile.FileName));` and I will assume that the left open part is coming from `File.OpenWrite(…)` which appears unnecessary as you said. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, of couse. `File.OpenWrite()` leaves the Stream open. I wrote about it in the comments you can see up there (I know, too many comments :).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to convert xml file to the datagridview.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = "E:\\test.xml";
            string str = File.ReadAllText(path);
            System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(str);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(sr);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Besides, I noted that your xml file has an error. Please try the following xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>123235435</Column1>
    <Column2>dffg</Column2>
    <Column3>ghh</Column3>
    <Column4>N/A</Column4>
    <Column5>100k</Column5>
    <Column6>False</Column6>
    <Column7>False</Column7>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Tested result:
[image]

Finally, if you want to convert datagirdview to datatable.

You can try the code like:

```
  DataTable table = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```